# Flask jinja2 how to separate header, base and footer?

Tags: flask, jinja2

I have a question that in my base.html, I have :

```
<div id="header">{% block header %}{% endblock %}</div>
<div id="content">{% block content %}{% endblock %}</div>
<div id="footer">{% block footer %}{% endblock %}</div>
```

For every other page, I always do this:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block content %}
...
```

My question is that I do not want to have my header (or footer) code inside base.html because it's a lot of things, is there anyway that i can have separate files like header.html and footer.html that my "base.html" will get the content from, and every other page which extends "base.html" will also display the content of the header.html and footer.html?

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Yeah, you can do that using the include statement. So in base.html, wherever you want the content of header.html you put this:

```
{% include "header.html" %}
```

http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/templates/#include